# How can I access and use an external sqlite database file stored someone on my computer using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, sqlite, external

Ultimately I want to be able to access this sqlite database from multiple programs locally primarily via website and probably (c# application which I already know how to do). So I don't think that a websql is what I'm looking for.. (unless it is?) I want an actual sqlite database file I can store anywhere on my computer and access it/manipulate it through a browser without any back-end processing.

Does anyone know of any good tutorials for this? I can't seem to find information on how to do this.

Comment: the hard part with what you describe would be updating the sql file from browser JS.

Comment: Yeah, after searching  a bit more it almost seems like browsers won't allow this type of behavior.

Comment: you can make changes and download a new file, but you cannot update the old one in the old folder.

Comment: That's helpful to know. Perhaps I'll have to take the route of trying to manipulate everything through a c# web-browser somehow, though it sounds painful firing events from web-browser inside a windows form. Maybe I'll just have to come up with a different plan altogether.